# Как записать видео приложения для AppStore

Tags: ios, apple, appstore

Как записать видео работы приложения для AppStore? [Инструкция с сайта Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/imovie/) не помогает, т.к. iTunes Connect требует специфическое разрешение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А этого разрешения нет ни в QuickTime Player:
[image: QuickTime Player]

ни в iMovie:

[image: iMovie]

*"To export the final video, click Share in the toolbar, then choose App Preview"*

Пункта App Preview просто нет.

Приветствуются любые идеи.

Comment: В видеоредакторе поправь потом

Comment: @Allespro Можете посоветовать, в каком? Те редакторы под Mac, которые я смотрел не позволяют выбрать произвольное разрешение.

Comment: У меня установлен Kdenlive, и если я не ошибаюсь, то он и под mac доступен. Или вот ещё https://www.shotcut.org/download/. В Kdenlive точно произвольное можно выставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простое.
В iMovie при создании проекта надо выбрать File - New App Preview

[image: iMovie]

Оставлю ответ тут, думаю кому-нибудь пригодится.